# Add multiple products to an order - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an inventory management system. I'm having problems figuring out how to add multiple inventory items into my order from a table. I want to achieve this by selecting the item by the checkbox and also adding the quantity. I also eventually want to add a search bar to search through the table

html

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group row">
            <Label for="id_{{ field.name }}" class="col-2 col-form-label">{{ field.label }}</Label>
            <div class="col-10">
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
            {% for item in Inventory %}
                <tr>
                    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheck" value="{{ item.pk }} "></td>
                    <td> <input name="itemQuantity"> </td>
                    <td> {{ item.name }} </td>
                    <td> {{ item.quantity }} </td>
                    <td> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">{{item.status}}</span></td>
                    <td> ${{ item.sale_price }} </td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

views.py

```
def create_order(request):
    order_form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if formset.is_valid():
            total = 0
            order = Orders(total=total)
            order.save()
            order_form.save()
            selected_items = request.POST.getlist('itemCheck')
            print(selected_items) # This returns the primary keys of the selected items

    context = {"form": order_form, "Inventory": Inventory.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'create_order.html', context)
```

models

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
      ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id} - {self.name}"


class Orders(models.Model):
    studio = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="warehouse", blank=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class OrderEquipment(models.Model):
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
```

Comment: You can probably loop through the `selected_items` collection.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, since you didn't post your formset and other code, I'm going to assume your HTML and formset are coming in correctly and just focus on the table/model loading.  I have found the best way to load many items is to use bulk_create().  You may need to fidget around with the below code, but it should get you on the right track.

```
from django.db import transaction

try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            # I put cleaned_data below.  You need to replace with your Orders data if different.
            order = Orders.objects.create(**cleaned_data)

            # Loop thru OrderEquipment Items.  I'm guessing your 'selected_items' is the inventory data, (equipment and quantity).
            orderequip_list = []
            for equip in selected_items:
                orderequip_list.append(OrderEquipment(order=order, **equip))

            OrderEquipment.objects.bulk_create(orderequip_list)
    except (IntegrityError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
        order = None
```